# React custom hook referring to incorrect function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have custom hook to manage cookies in React. As shown in the definition below, `getCookie()` only has one argument and `setCookie()` has 2-7 arguments. So whenever I try to get cookie through `getCookie()` function, the `setCookie()` function being called and code does not compile.

**useCookies.tsx**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

/**
 * A hook to get, save, update and delete browser cookies through JavaScript
 *
 * @author Pavan Kumar Jadda
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
export default function useCookies() {

    /**
     * Get cookie Regular Expression
     *
     * @param name Cookie name
     * @returns property RegExp
     *
     * @author Pavan Kumar Jadda
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    function getCookieRegExp(name: string): RegExp {
        return new RegExp('(?:^' + name + '|;\\s*' + name + ')=(.*?)(?:;|$)', 'g')
    }

    /**
     * Return `true` if {@link Document} is accessible, otherwise return `false`
     *
     * @param name Cookie name
     * @returns boolean - whether cookie with specified name exists
     *
     * @author Pavan Kumar Jadda
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    function check(name: string): boolean {
        name = encodeURIComponent(name)
        const regExp: RegExp = getCookieRegExp(name)
        return regExp.test(document.cookie)
    }

    /**
     * Decodes a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) component
     * @param encodedURIComponent
     *
     * @returns string - decoded URI component
     *
     * @author Pavan Kumar Jadda
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    function safeDecodeURIComponent(encodedURIComponent: string): string {
        try {
            return decodeURIComponent(encodedURIComponent)
        } catch {
            // probably it is not uri encoded. return as is
            return encodedURIComponent
        }
    }


    /**
     * Get cookies by name
     *
     * @param name Cookie name
     * @returns property value
     *
     * @author Pavan Kumar Jadda
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    function getCookie(name: string): string {
        if (check(name)) {
            name = encodeURIComponent(name)
            const result: RegExpExecArray | null = getCookieRegExp(name).exec(document.cookie)
            return result !== null && result[1] ? safeDecodeURIComponent(result[1]) : ''
        } else {
            return ''
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get all cookies in JSON format
     *
     * @returns all the cookies in json
     *
     * @author Pavan Kumar Jadda
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    function getAllCookies(): { [key: string]: string } {
        const cookies: { [key: string]: string } = {}
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
            document.cookie.split(';').forEach((currentCookie) => {
                const [cookieName, cookieValue] = currentCookie.split('=')
                cookies[safeDecodeURIComponent(cookieName.replace(/^ /, ''))] = safeDecodeURIComponent(cookieValue)
            })
        }
        return cookies
    }

    /**
     * Set cookie based on provided information
     *
     * @param name     Cookie name
     * @param value    Cookie value
     * @param expiresOrOptions  Number of days until the cookies expires or an actual `Date`
     * @param path  Cookie path. Defaults to '/'
     * @param domain  Cookie domain
     * @param secure  Secure flag
     * @param sameSite  OWASP same site token `Lax`, `None`, or `Strict`. Defaults to `Lax`
     *
     * @author Pavan Kumar Jadda
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    function setCookie(name: string, value: string, expiresOrOptions?: number | Date | any, path?: string, domain?: string, secure?: boolean, sameSite?: 'Lax' | 'None' | 'Strict'): void
    {
        if (typeof expiresOrOptions === 'number' || expiresOrOptions instanceof Date || path || domain || secure || sameSite) {
            const optionsBody = {
                expires: expiresOrOptions,
                path,
                domain,
                secure,
                sameSite: sameSite || 'Lax'
            }
            setCookie(name, value, optionsBody)
            return;
        }

        let cookieString: string = encodeURIComponent(name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value) + ';'

        const options = expiresOrOptions || {}
        if (options.expires) {
            if (typeof options.expires === 'number') {
                const dateExpires: Date = new Date(
                    new Date().getTime() + options.expires * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
                )

                cookieString += 'expires=' + dateExpires.toUTCString() + ';'
            } else {
                cookieString += 'expires=' + options.expires.toUTCString() + ';'
            }
        }

        if (options.path) {
            cookieString += 'path=' + options.path + ';'
        }

        if (options.domain) {
            cookieString += 'domain=' + options.domain + ';'
        }

        if (options.secure === false && options.sameSite === 'None') {
            options.secure = true
            console.warn(
                `[ngx-cookie-service] Cookie ${name} was forced with secure flag because sameSite=None.` +
                `More details : https://github.com/stevermeister/ngx-cookie-service/issues/86#issuecomment-597720130`
            )
        }
        if (options.secure) {
            cookieString += 'secure;'
        }

        if (!options.sameSite) {
            options.sameSite = 'Lax'
        }

        cookieString += 'sameSite=' + options.sameSite + ';'
        document.cookie = cookieString
    }

    /**
     * Delete cookie by name
     *
     * @param name   Cookie name
     * @param path   Cookie path
     * @param domain Cookie domain
     * @param secure Cookie secure flag
     * @param sameSite Cookie sameSite flag
     *
     * @author Pavan Kumar Jadda
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    function deleteCookie(name: string, path ?: string, domain ?: string, secure ?: boolean, sameSite: 'Lax' | 'None' | 'Strict' = 'Lax'): void {
        const cookies = document.cookie.split("; ");
        for (let c = 0; c < cookies.length; c++) {
            const d = window.location.hostname.split(".");
            while (d.length > 0) {
                const cookieBase = encodeURIComponent(cookies[c].split(";")[0].split("=")[0]) + '=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; domain=' + d.join('.') + ' ;path=';
                const p = window.location.pathname.split('/');
                document.cookie = cookieBase + '/';
                while (p.length > 0) {
                    document.cookie = cookieBase + p.join('/');
                    p.pop();
                }
                d.shift();
            }
        }
        const expiresDate = new Date('Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT')
        setCookie(name, '', {expires: expiresDate, path, domain, secure, sameSite})
    }

    /**
     * Delete all cookies
     *
     * @param path   Cookie path
     * @param domain Cookie domain
     * @param secure Is the Cookie secure
     * @param sameSite Is the cookie same site
     *
     * @author Pavan Kumar Jadda
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    function deleteAllCookies(
        path?: string,
        domain?: string,
        secure?: boolean,
        sameSite: 'Lax' | 'None' | 'Strict' = 'Lax'
    ): void {
        const cookies: any = getAllCookies()
        for (const cookieName in cookies) {
            /* eslint-disable */
            if (cookies.hasOwnProperty(cookieName)) {
                deleteCookie(cookieName, path, domain, secure, sameSite)
            }
        }
    }

    //Return hooks
    return [  getCookie, getAllCookies, setCookie, deleteCookie, deleteAllCookies];
}
```

**Login.tsx**
Here is the Login component

```
export default function Login(): JSX.Element {
const [getCookie] = useCookies();
console.log('getCookie',getCookie('isLoggedIn'));
}
```

**Error**

[image: custom hook error]

Comment: Are you sure `getCookie` is pointing to the right function there? What's the type of `getCookie` according to intellisense? Seems cut off in your screenshot. And it'd be handy to have your code using the hook as a non-screenshot.

Comment: Is `getCookie` the first element returned from the hook in the `console` call? I'd recommend you have your hook return an object instead of an array to avoid this kind of confusion.

Comment: If you're returning so many things from your hook you might consider using an object with named properties instead of that long array.

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs updated hook code

Comment: More important than the code of your hook here is the code that's using the hook.

Comment: It looks like the order of the items in your array changed with the last edit of your post, so that will break any code that uses your hook.  Definitely try to use an object instead of that array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your updated code, the problem looks pretty obvious:

Your hook returns `[ cookies, getCookie, getAllCookies, ...` while your `Login.tsx` uses `const [getCookie] = useCookies();`. Your `getCookie` is indeed pointing at the wrong thing.

Perhaps it's easier if return an object, e.g. like this:

```js
function useHook() {
  // ....
  return { cookie, getCookie, etc };
}

// somewhere in Login.tsx
const { getCookie } = useHook();
```

Then the order doesn't matter.

Comment: That's the problem. Thanks for answer. How dumb of me?

Comment: Can happen to anyone. And using arrays like this is very common, i.e. even React's `useState` uses it. But when you start returning a ton of values, it might be a lot easier (and less error-prone) to use an object where you can properly name the fields.